# Fixed bar script makes slideshow "jump" - How to remove?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i couldnt find a better tittle because its a specific error of my site, that i will provide a link to see it and his code.

The issue is when i scroll, there is a script that when the bar touches the top of the browser, the bar will remain there, but that make the slideshow make a little jump and the bars cuts part of the slideshow.

See it here: http://optential.co.nf/

Code:

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
  var h = $('.header').height();
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > h) {
    $('.mail2, .optimize').addClass('fixed');
    
  } else {
    $('.mail2, .optimize').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("img/fundo1.jpg");
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .logo {
  width: 230px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 8px 8px 6%;
}

.header .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px; right: 25px;
}

.header .menu a {
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

.header .menu a:hover,
.header .menu a.current {
  color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
}

.header .move {
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header .move .center {
  margin: 260px auto 0;
  width: 360px;
}

.header .move h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.header .move p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.header .mail1 {
  background-image: url("img/email.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 560px; height: 560px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.header .mail1 form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  bottom: 220px; right: 155px;
}

.header .mail1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);

}
.header .mail1 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
 }

.header .mail1 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.header .mail1 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.header .mail1 a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header .mail1 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/barra.png");
  background-position: 12% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
}

#btn {
    width: 10em; 
  }

.mail2.fixed {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  position: fixed;
  display:block;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mail2 form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 600px;
}

.mail2 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mail2 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.mail2 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.mail2 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.mail2 a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 4%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mail2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 .top {
  padding: 8px 6px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.mail2 .top:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

#slider {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .images { 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s;
  left: 0;
}

#slider .images img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}

.controls {
  width:100%;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.controls div {

  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.controls .current {
  background: red;
}

.barra2 {
  background-image: url('img/barra2.png');
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 21.6%;
}

.mobile {
  background-image: url("img/fundos.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 44.4%;
  position: relative;
}

#pc {
  height: 600px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-size: 100%
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image: url("img/pc.jpg");
}

#pctexto {
  height: 600px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: blue;
}
.mobile .invisi {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13%;
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 14%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.mobile .invisi:hover {
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.mobile .appstore {
  right: 26.5%;
}

.mobile .googleplay {
  right: 11.5%;
}

.contact {
  background-image: url("img/fundo2es.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  color:white;
}

.contact .textocon {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 55px 75px 0 0;
}

.contact .textocon div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px
}

.contact .textocon h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.contact .textocon p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.contact .col1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 410px;
  padding: 10px 6px 10px 60px;
}

.contact .col1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.contact .col1 input {
  width: 380px;
  height: 20px;
}

.contact .col1 input,
.contact .col2 textarea {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgb(172, 161, 160);
  margin: 6px 0;
}
.contact .col1 input:focus,
.contact .col2 textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact .col2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 560px);
  padding: 52px 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.contact .col2 textarea {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 112px;
}

.contact .col2 #btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.contact .col2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.contact .info {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact .info h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.contact .info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.contact .info a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.contact .info a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.contact .info img {
  width: 32px;
  margin: 6px;
}
.contact .info img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixedbar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title> Layout </title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="header" id="top">
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
        <a href="#tour">Product Tour</a>
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a href="#">Try</a>
        <a href="#vision">Vision</a>
      </div>
      <div class="move">
        <div class="center">
          <h1>Move work forward!</h1>
          <p>Optential keeps your team organized, connected, and focused on results.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mail1">
        <form action="form/form.php" method="post">
          <h1>Try Now!</h1>
          <input name="Email" class="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email address ...">
          <input type="submit" value="Get started for free">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mail2">
        <form action="form/form.php" method="post">
        <h1>Try Now!</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email here...">
        <input type="submit" id ="btn" value="Get started for free">
        <a class="top" href="#top">Top</a>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="slider">
        <div class="images">
          <div class="controls">
          <img src="img/3.png" alt="Image-1" />
          <img src="img/2.png" alt="Image-2" />
          <img src="img/1.png" alt="Image-3" />
          <img src="img/4.png" alt="Image-4" />
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="barra2"></div>

    <div class="mobile">
      <div id="pc"> 

      </div>

      <div id="pctexto">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <div class="textocon">
        <div>
          <h1>Optential</h1>
          <p>A new management system<br>for a new management paradigm!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" action="form/contactengine.php">
        <div class="col1">
          <h1>Contact us!</h1>
          <input type="text" name="Name" size="50" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" name="Email" size="50" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="text" name="Subject" size="50" placeholder="Subject"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <textarea name="Message" rows="5" cols="70" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
          <input type="submit" id="btn"value="Send"/>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="info">
        <div>
          <h1>Mail Us !</h1>
          <p>Rua Andrade Corvo, 242</p>
          <p>sala 206</p>
          <p>4700-204 Braga</p>
          <p>Portugal</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Call Us !</h1>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Email Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><p>code@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_hr@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_support@angel.com</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Join Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/gplus.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/instag.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The css of the bar is "mail2", of the slideshow is "slider" and "controls".

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply `.fixed`, you are taking the menu element out of the flow.  This is because it is changing from `position: relative` to `position: fixed`. That's why the elements below it are jumping up 100px .  To complete the effect you're after, you will need to compensate for the missing 100px.

**OPTION 1**

You can apply a `margin-top` to the `#slider` element below:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > h) {
   $('.mail2, .optimize').addClass('fixed');
   $('#slider').css('margin-top', '100px');

} else {
  $('.mail2, .optimize').removeClass('fixed');
  $('#slider').css('margin-top', '0px');
}
```

**OPTION 2**

You can add an element with 100px of height into the flow.

In your HTML, add this below the `.mail2` element

```
<div id="menu-block" style="height: 100px; display: none;">
```

And add this to your JS:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > h) {
  $('.mail2, .optimize').addClass('fixed');
  $('#menu-block').css('display', 'block');

} else {
  $('.mail2, .optimize').removeClass('fixed');
  $('#menu-block').css('display', 'none');
}
```

In this particular case, both ways will work the same.  In other situations, only one technique will be suitable. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Considering the bar is a fixed height of `100px`, you could add a rule like so:

```
.fixed + #slider {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

or if other pages have more dynamic layouts, you could use `.fixed + *`

Comment: @BugaDroid You're welcome.  Glad I could help.  Note that tylerism better explained the cause.  You may have to seek other methods to maintain that gap that appears when the bar is made `fixed`, so it's good to know the reason behind the sudden collapsed space.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle I appreciate it. While I gave a good explanation, you have definitely delivered a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is because as soon as you make it be `position:fixed` it no longer takes up space on the page, so the content under it jumps up to fill the space.

I have come across this in the past, and my solution was to put another div under the bar that is going to get fixed. It needs to be the same height as the div that is going to become fixed. Make it `display:none` and then change it to `display:block` when you toggle the bar to be fixed, that way it appears right when the fixed bar stops taking up space on the page. This should stop it from jumping.